# Using ng-options with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I am getting some data back from my server. The data structure is:

```
[{"sectorName1": "nameHere",
  "subSectors": ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
 },
 {"sectorName2": "nameHere",
  "subSectors": ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
 }]
```

I am trying to display each sectors subSectors with ng-options. So when some uses the dropdown they will see all the subsectors.

**I have tried this but doesn't seem to work:**

```
<select id="selectSubSector" class="form-control" name="subSector" ng-model="item" ng-options="sec for sec in mySectors.subSectors ">
</select>
```

*where mySectors is the data that comes back from the server.*

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does not work? console errors? no options in the select?

Comment: @JohannesJander no options. Select remains empty

Comment: and what is `mySectors`? Could it be you wanted to write `mySectors[0].subsectors`?

Comment: @JohannesJander `mySectors` is the data that comes from the server. It contains the objects as shown in the data structure in the question. Those objects then contain a nested subSectors array. And that what I want, that nested subSectors array.

Comment: Well, then you need to use `mySectors[0].subsectors` if you do not want to aggregate the subsectors of several sectors - which is just a simple `map` operation

Comment: do you wish to display each of the subSectors in same `option` or different for each of the sector of the subSector?

Comment: @Shashank so sub1, sub2, sub3 should in different `option` BUT within the same `select`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes Lorenzo, but is it mandatory to make use of `ng-options`, as in, one could also make use of `ng-repeat` in options?

Comment: @Shashank I tried using ng-repeat. But that was also repeat the whole `select` as its a nested array. I had to use 2 ng-repeats.

Comment: @LorenzovonMatterhorn  use one ng-repeat on base object `mySectors ` and other will be done by ng-option. Or tell how should it look like /some kind of demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/mq3sr829/), have updated your response data as well:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <select ng-model="selectData">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <optgroup ng-repeat='item in data' label="{{item.sectorName}}">
            <option ng-repeat="option in item.subSectors">{{option}}</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
        "sectorName": "nameHere1",
        "subSectors": ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
    },
     {
         "sectorName": "nameHere2",
         "subSectors": ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
     }];
});
```

Comment: Amazingly done. So simple! No idea why I couldn't think of it. Nice one mate!

Comment: Thankx dude. Request to please accept the answer, if it works for your case

Answer (score 1):

i have create a plunker:https://plnkr.co/edit/3QkxdT6P8upwhwttUSDc?p=preview

the js code:

```
  $scope.mySectors = [{
    "sectorName1": "nameHere",
    "subSectors": ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
  }, {
    "sectorName2": "nameHere",
    "subSectors": ["sub1", "sub2", "sub3"]
  }];

  $scope.subSectors = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.mySectors.length; i++) {
       for(var j=0; j< $scope.mySectors[i].subSectors.length; j++){

    $scope.subSectors.push($scope.mySectors[i].subSectors[j]);
       }
  }
```

the html code:

```
<select id="selectSubSector" class="form-control" name="subSector" ng-model="item" ng-options="sec for sec in subSectors"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Nice technique, I should've thought of filleting the data in the controller before sending it to the view. Learned something new. Cheers mate. +1

Answer (score 0):

mySectors is an array. So there is no mySectors.subSectors. You have to specify index for mySectors. For example mySectors[i].subsectors

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and a solution to just display the sub-sections by using `ng-if="false"` or `style="display: none"` and `ng-repeat-start/end`.

```
<div ng-repeat="sector in Sectors">
<select>
    <option ng-repeat-start="subSectors in sector.subSectors" ng-if="false"></option>
    <option ng-repeat-end ng-repeat="subSectorValue in subSectors" value="{{ subSectorValue }}">{{ subSectorValue }}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

This gives us a select box with the following options.

- sub1
- sub2
- sub3
- etc