# Selecting From an Array with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, select, select-options

How would I use a Select Option in AngularJS to select item in multiple item array.  This is for a google map API application.  If I select Manager1, I want to return the markers resolved to Bert Bingham etc.  The examples I found is to list the items in an array[], but it doesn't return anything this way.  Thanks!

#### JSON

```
var sites= [
    {name: "ABC",ISE:["Bert Bingham","Manager1"],lat:"29.9792183",lng:"-90.22268919999999"},
    {name: "Ajax",ISE:["Bert Bingham","Manager1"],lat:"30.0032515",lng:"-90.22060119999999"},
    {name: "CBS",ISE:["Bing Bingle","Manager2"],lat:"31.9703011",lng:"-90.08290799999999"},
    {name: "Turner",ISE:["Bing Bingle","Manager2"],lat:"31.004759",lng:"-90.17053299999999"},   
];
```

#### HTML

```
<div ng-app="mapsApp" ng-controller="MapCtrl">

    <div align ="center" class ="input-w">
        <div class ="gulf">Gulf States</div>

        <fieldset>

          <label>ISE: </label> 
          <select id ="ISEs" class="dropdown" name="singleSelect"
                  ng-model="data.singleSelect"
                  ng-change="filterMarkers();centerMap()">
             <option value="0">all</option>
             <option id ="1"  value="Bert Bingham">Bert Bingham</option>
             <option id = "2" value="Bing Bingle">Bing Bingle</option>
             <option id = "2" value="Manager1">Manager1</option>
             <option id = "2" value="Manager2">Manager2</option>

          </select><br><br>
       </fieldset>
    </div> 
    <div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: you can add multiple attribute on select to select multiple options so in that way all selected values will show up in your model "data.singleSelect" as array.

Comment: I guess it seems same like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35173373/using-ng-options-with-nested-arrays